# Redis Search by two values for PostList (Zsets)

Tags: redis, nosql

i am using Mac 10.13 , redis 4.0.8

hash Post:PostUID has

```
UserUID,PostUID,UserAge,CreateDate,LastUpdate,Cotent
create and zadd PostList
```

zset PostList has Post:PostUID

```
Score : UserAge , Member : Post:PostUID
```

i want Search by UserAge and sort by LastUpdate and use Limit offset 20

if i want search UserAge 15~18
i tried zrevrangebyscore 18 15 limit 0 20

this commands success search by UserAge but sort by entered

how to sort by LastUpdate?

if

```
Post:1 is UserAge 15 LastUpdate 201804260000
Post:2 is UserAge 16 LastUpdate 201804251530
Post:3 is UserAge 15 LastUpdate 201804232020
Post:4 is UserAge 17 Lastupdate 201804252200
```

i want Post:1 , Post:4 ,Post:2 , Post:3

but result is 4 2 3 1

Comment: What have you tried? Have you read the page at https://redis.io/topics/indexes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to take a look at [RediSearch](http://redisearch.io/) module for this. Redis out of the box doesn't support searching over multiple hashes -- you would have to iterate over every post to see which ones match. RediSearch indexes your data for querying